# In which scenario would this kind of if statement be useful? `if (condition);`

Tags: java

Today I read this line of Java code:

```
if (results.add(userName));
```

For me, it is the first `if` statement I've ever seen which does not have a then or else clause. I was surprised that it is not a syntax error.

So is there any use of this kind of `if` statement at all? That is, an `if` without then or else clause.

Comment: Yeah, you'll occasionally see a `for` or `while` statement with a null body, using only the side effect of the expression evaluation, but there's no "point" in doing this with `if`.

Comment: It is just a waste. An unnecessary condition check for no reason. But I am not sure how it is compiled to the byte code.

Comment: It is much more make sense if it were used in a `for` or `while` such as `for (;;list.remove(elm));` or `while (list.remove(elm));` to remove all matching elements in a list

Comment: Or, `for(char c = 'Z'; c >= 'A'; System.out.println(c--));` `for(Iterator iter = coll.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); doSomething(iter.next()));` etc..

Comment: Just curious, where did you see this piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No use. It's very likely a typo. It's not a special if statement, however. The `;` is a statement, the empty statement, which from the language's point of view, is equivalent to an empty block `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The only use I can think of is to show the reader that you "could" check for the return value but currently are not interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it has no use, i.e. the `if` is not doing anything additional. **But**, it could very well serve to remind/show the reader of the code that `results.add(userName)` actually returns a *boolean*, and is not *void* as one might suspect if the `if` was not there.

Comment: IMHO, it's not the job of a client code to remind a reader what a method returns. It's a part of the method specification and the job of the reader to go read the documentation if required. It only hampers the readability of the client code.

Comment: @BheshGurung I completely agree with you, I would never do something like this myself. I was just trying to think of any possible benefits it could have. And bear in mind that the writer could be the reader a year later.

Comment: In many cases code can be a better piece of documentation that any external documentation. That said, this use of `if` is not what I would use myself even for documentation purposes.